# iOS (Swift): UITextField is **not** first responder after becomeFirstResponder method is called?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

I have an array of `UITextField`s inside a `UIViewController`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!
var textFields: [UITextField] {
    return [textField1, textField2]
}
```

In my `viewDidLoad` method, I set the first element of the `textFields` array to be the first responder and set all of their delegates as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textFields[0].becomeFirstResponder()
    textFields.forEach({ $0.delegate = self })

    print(textFields.map({ $0.isFirstResponder })) // [false, false]

}
```

However, the print statement in the `viewDidLoad` prints `[false, false]` rather than `[true, false]` as I might have expected. Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're running this code too soon. No text field can become first responder during `viewDidLoad`, because no text field is even in the interface yet.

To put it another way, try changing your code to:

```
print(textFields.map({ $0.window == nil }))
```

You'll get `[true, true]`, proving that the text fields are not yet in any window. But first responder status is window-based; a free-floating text field cannot be first responder.

Comment: Hi Matt, it would appear that `textField1` is becoming the first responder though?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't actually happen until later.

Comment: But "loaded" does not mean what you think it means. It is not weird at all.

Comment: Yep you're right. I need the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method instead ...

Comment: And thanks for your help. I'll mark this right in a bit.